# what does @const mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

We are considering adopting the [Google JavaScript coding guidelines](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) within our company to maintain consistency across projects but one thing is confusing me. In the section on [constants](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Constants#Constants) it says to use the `@const` keyword annotation for compile-time constant enforcement but I have never come across the `@` symbol before. Is this a Google extension or part of the core language?

Here is the full text:

> For non-primitives, use the `@const` annotation.

```
/**  
* The number of seconds in each of the given units.  
* @type {Object.<number>}  
* @const  
*/
goog.example.SECONDS_TABLE = {  
  minute: 60,
  hour: 60 * 60
  day: 60   * 60 * 24
}
```

> This allows the compiler to enforce constant-ness.
>
> As for the `const` keyword, Internet Explorer doesn't parse it, so don't use it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JSDoc annotations as this one can be used to give hints to the **Google Closure Compiler** as described in [this page](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html). Again, this is not part of the language, and the use of @constant (beside adding some information for your fellow programmer) is relevant only if you use the closure compiler in your project.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's referring to the use of @const in JSDoc (Think JavaDoc) to mark certain objects constant.

It's not a javascript keyword and not a part of the language – just something used in inline documentation in JSDoc.

Edit: The mention of 'never use the const keyword' may confuse you. The guidelines tell not to use const because IE doesn't support it, **instead** marking the "constants" constant in the documentation.

Some javascript compiler might parse JSdoc for notation like that, but I doubt it's standard.

Comment: I highly doubt any mainstream js engine parses JSDoc